# ASP.NET MVC routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My routing is not working properly.  I have the following routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "CategoryDetails",
     url: "{seoName}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "ContactUs",
     url: "contact",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "AboutUs",
     url: "about",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I click on the about us or contact us links then it takes me to the details action method in the category controller.

This is the markup for my about us and contact us links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")
```

My details action method for the category controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string seoName)
{
     CategoryViewModel model = categoryTask.Details(seoName);

     return View(model);
}
```

What is wrong with my route configuration?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Reorder your routes from most specific to less specific. That way the routes for contact and about will come before the seoName route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ContactUs",
        url: "contact",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AboutUs",
        url: "about",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CategoryDetails",
        url: "{seoName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With your original order, the urls`~/contact` and `~/about` would always be handled by the seoName route. By reordering them, you make sure they are handled by the proper actions in the `HomeController` and the seoName route will only match a url after the contact and about routes have failed to match.

Answer (score 3):

The CategoryDetails route is defined first. That's why it matches for example the url "`http://server/AboutUs`" (seoName will be assigned "AboutUs"). The most specific routes (AboutUs, ContactUs) should be defined first.

Answer (score 1):

The following is causing the issue for you. please comment it out or place at the bottom.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "CategoryDetails",
     url: "{seoName}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details" }
);
```

Initally the Defualt route works and you are taken HomeControllers Indeax action.

When  you click any Link. the routing engines matches the first one. the default values  specified in the route definition are taken.

Try adding following line  in controller and view . so that you will understand how and were  you are going wrong

```
public ActionResult Details(string seoName)
    {
        ViewBag.ValueReceived = seoName;
        return View();
    }
```

And in View

```
<h1>@ViewBag.ValueReceived</h1>
```

When Clicking Contact or Details  the url will be resembling

http://arunkumar.com:62115/about

Here the 'about' is considered as value for seoName and the wrong routing is chosen

Comment: Good explanation of how one might debug and arrive at the correct conclusion, as well as the answer the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error, i was putting

```
HttpPost("/route")
```

instead of

```
HttpPost("route")
```